# How to add few rows of a specific table in outlook (Either as attachment or in body of the email)

Tags: sql, oracle, email

I have a table, based on a condition, I have to fetch few rows in outlook either as attachment or in the body of email

sample table:

```
S.No    Name    Product Amount  Date
   1    Answ    A       1000    01-09-2019
   2    Ahja    B        500    01-09-2019
   3    abn     C        200    01-09-2019
   4    amn     D        100    01-09-2019
   5    Aok     E        100    01-09-2019
   6    Ahe     F        600    01-09-2019
   7    Qwe     G        400    01-09-2019
```

I want to filter all the rows greater than 400 and send email to specific stakeholders in outlook

Output expected:

```
S.No    Name    Product Amount  Date
1       Answ    A       1000    01-09-2019
2       Ahja    B        500    01-09-2019
6       Ahe     F        600    01-09-2019
```

which has to be emailed to specific stakeholders using outlook automatically

Comment: What have you tried?  Unless I'm missing something, looks like a `where` clause is all you need...

Comment: So does your database server have Outlook installed on it? Does it have any email server? The easy bit is formatting email in PL/SQL: use the built-in `utl_mail` package. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_mail.htm#BABFJJBD).

Comment: Yes,We have UTL_mail package

Comment: Yes I'm using UTL_mail package, but how to add the table values in the email body is what I'm missing. I can add free text in email body but not values from a table

Comment: @sgeddes, I have posted my response, do you have any response for the same?